# Quickbooks web connector OwnerID/FileID usage

Tags: quickbooks

I would like to know what exactly does `OwnerID/FileID` in a QWC file signify. I went through the QBWC_proguide but still it is somewhat unclear to me. I am new to this so please can somebody elaborate this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to know what exactly does OwnerID/FileID in a QWC file signify.

Nothing.  :-/

They really serve no purpose *except* to make sure that you can't load the same `.QWC` file twice. You can safely make up these values (they have to be valid GUID values) and even change them if you need to legitimately re-load a .QWC file and QuickBooks won't let you.

Comment: Thank alot for the quick response!. Also, does that mean that in multi-user mode two different users cannot use the same(OwnerID/FileID) QWC file.

Comment: You can't have the same OwnerID/FileID combination loaded into QuickBooks twice, regardless of who or how you try to load it.

Comment: I know this answer is 4 years old, but I feel you just saved me that much time trying to dig myself out of a QuickBooks quagmire. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Keith's answer, while it does prevent you from adding the same company connector config twice, I believe you can also pass OwnerID to the CompanyRq query to get back the FileId, which is unique for each company and can be used for multi-connect

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65679466/2807183 for more details