# How to get Quickbooks Desktop Web Connector to initiate a connection?

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, quickbooks

I'm trying to build a node service to pull information from Quickbooks Desktop. The most logical route seems to be the Quickbooks Desktop Web Connector.

I have tried with both quickbooks-js and creating a node-soap class from the wsdl and while the server runs fine, I don't see any logs about connections.

From the client side, I have been trying to connect to this nodejs service, but QBWC almost immediately stops responding. This is the full log for attempting to add my connection:

> Log file initialized at Monday, January 11, 2021 - 7:44 AM UTC
> Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC QBWebConnector 2.2 has
> been initialized with its logging status to level = DEBUG. Please
> restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. Use
> file menu to clear log.
>
> 20210111.07:44:08 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been
> set to False
> 20210111.07:44:08 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
> 20210111.07:44:09 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been
> set to False
> 20210111.07:44:09 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
> 20210111.07:44:09 UTC : QBWebConnector_Load() :  QuickBooks Web Connector 2.3.0.198 has started. Monday, January 11, 2021 at 7:44:09
> AM
> 20210111.07:44:09 UTC : QBWebConnector_Load() : QBWC Form Loaded
> 20210111.07:44:20 UTC : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -    Troubleshoot access via QuickBooks
> IDNTS_FS1
> https://8001-XXX.ws-eu03.gitpod.io
> Helps troubleshoot QBWebConnector for
> QuickBooks
> https://8001-XXX.ws-eu03.gitpod.io
> test
> {A9A83089-7DA7-4d27-A08C-7E1626E9395A}
> {AE931E67-4AA5-4374-A32D-8EA4BEC91981}
> QBFS   Document
> 0xF 
> 20210111.07:44:20 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing
> application configuration xml file to load its content to variables

From the client side, I have tried the Quickbooks testing connection, and received the following logfile (looks like it worked):

> Log file initialized at Friday, January 8, 2021 - 12:25 PM UTC
> Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC QBWebConnector 2.2 has
> been initialized with its logging status to level = DEBUG. Please
> restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. Use
> file menu to clear log.
>
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been
> set to False
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been
> set to False
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector_Load() :  QuickBooks Web Connector 2.3.0.198 has started. Friday, January 8, 2021 at 12:25:31
> PM
> 20210108.12:25:31 UTC : QBWebConnector_Load() : QBWC Form Loaded
> 20210108.12:26:19 UTC : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -    Troubleshoot access via QuickBooks
> IDNTS_FS1
> https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx
> Helps troubleshoot QBWebConnector for
> QuickBooks
> http://developer.intuit.com/QBWebConnector/
> test
> {A9A83089-7DA7-4d27-A08C-7E1626E9395A}
> {AE931E67-4AA5-4374-A32D-8EA4BEC91981}
> QBFS   Document
> 0xF 
> 20210108.12:26:19 UTC : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing
> application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
> 20210108.12:26:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
> 20210108.12:26:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name
> 20210108.12:26:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving
> Troubleshoot access via QuickBooks to Registry: Object reference not
> set to an instance of an object.
> 20210108.12:26:30 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connected., Session started
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Application name =
> Troubleshoot access via QuickBooks
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Querying company
> file to find if owner/file id exists.
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Latest QBXML version supported = v14.0
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Querying QuickBooks for existance of owner/file id
> 20210108.12:26:52 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : XML dump follows: -
>
> onError="s......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : XML dump follows: -
>
> requestID="......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.findFileIDinQB() : Status message: A query request did not find a matching object in
> QuickBooks
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : FileID did not
> exist. Creating new FileID in company file
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Creating
> DataExtDef named FileID assigned to Company object for the ownerID =
> {A9A83089-7DA7-4d27-A08C-7E1626E9395A}
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> onError="s......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> requestID="1"......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Data extension
> definition has been created in QuickBooks for owner id.
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Registered FileID to
> company file successfully.
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> onError="s......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> requestID="1" st......
>
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.enterDataExtValueInQB() : Data extension
> value has been created in QuickBooks for FileID
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Entered FileID value
> to company file successfully.
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Creating
> DataExtDef named AppLock assigned to Company object for the ownerID =
> {A9A83089-7DA7-4d27-A08C-7E1626E9395A}
> 20210108.12:26:53 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> onError="s......
>
> 20210108.12:26:54 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> requestID="1"......
>
> 20210108.12:26:54 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.registerDataExtInQB() : Data extension
> definition has been created in QuickBooks for owner id.
> 20210108.12:26:54 UTC : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : Registered the
> AppLock to company file successfully.
> 20210108.12:26:54 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtDefAddRqXML() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> onError="s......
>
> 20210108.12:26:54 UTC : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_DataExtDefAddRqXML() : XML dump
> follows: -
>
> requestID="1"......

I tried rolling my own XML connection file based on the spec but I eventually copy-pasta'd the spec and just swapped out the URLs. The only file I can get any log after the variable line for is the Quickbooks test one.

I feel like if I can fix logging, I can at least see what the problem is so I have something to work with. I'm using Quickbooks Pro 2021 if that helps.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there seems to be some implied limit on the domain length. GitPod's domains are quite long and that seems to have caused the crash. It is undocumented to the best of my knowledge.